# Fill in the two missing places

Tags: mathematics, pattern

I've written down some numbers. There are two missing places which need to be filled in. There should not be ambiguity - the missing places have a unique solution.

**What are the missing numbers? And what is the meaning behind all the numbers?**

```
5 1
7 2
2 1
3 1
5 0
3 0
6 1
3 2
7 2
4 2
7 ?
? 5
```

**A hint for every day it is unsolved:**

**Hint 1:**

> There is a pattern here, but it's not in the numbers provided - it's from where the numbers came from. I also haven't said that each line is the only option - perhaps this is why the question is not "give the next line" where there are multiple options, but rather, "fill the missing places".

**Hint 2:**

> Why not try numbering the lines?

Comment: Does/can this pattern extend beyond what is shown?  Perhaps repeat?

Comment: Yes, it can go infinitely long. However, the continuation will not be unique. (as in, there are many different ways it could continue)

Comment: Gut feeling says the first ? is 7 and second ? is 3 but how to prove this still is a challenge.

Comment: Is this another US related puzzle? Please God let the answer be **No**.

Comment: Let us know if it requires any specific knowledge, say, states in US ! ;)

Comment: did these two columns of numbers begin with just 5 1 and then grow from there according to some rule such as a Fib series?????  What did it take to seed the sequences of numbers?

Comment: @Drt haha. I was willing to ask that question myself but thought the answer may spoil the puzzle.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir     I wouldn't usually ask such a question except that in this case it may be nearly impossible to solve the sequence.  It isn't binary bit shifting, different base number systems (although there is something kind of 'octal' about it)...just saying that a hint would be nice

Comment: @Drt I totally agree. Another thing I've noticed is that all the numbers are either sums or absolute diffs of two others (`30 = 51 - 21`, ...) but that doesn't have a rule neither. My only fear is that this is a US related puzzle as eedrah's [**other two questions**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41731/eedrah?tab=questions) were also related to US, in which case many won't have a clue (me included).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir  I was thinking the same thing and so just eliminated the possibility that it was a list of the number of counties in the different states...that wouldn't produce an "infinitely long" list of numbers...and the "many different ways" implies that there is no RULE!!  Or that there is a rule that changes for some reason.  It isn't area codes either...no matter how you dissect the lists

Comment: Good thinking everyone. To answer a question, and gives a point in the right direction, note that the other two questions had a "knowledge" tag and were part of a series. This one does not have a "knowledge" tag, but replaces it with a "mathematics" tag.

Comment: Your last comment, @Drt, has some good thinking, and your conversation, @ ibrahim-mahirir. Would you like me to comment on this? (It will give a pretty big hint)

Comment: Most certainly...please do provide a hint.  I am running out of ideas to go after.  I just eliminated the number of Presidents from each state and now am thinking that this may be a number problem...Hint please

Comment: Yep, to be explicit - no knowledge required, only mathematics

Comment: Hint provided, and the promise of more.

Comment: The given puzzle has 12 sets - suggesting 12 months of a year. Then coming to the numbers in the second column, perhaps - either they represent number of ___ or ___ (like consonants / unique vowels / common letters like **R**) in the names of the months, though no idea on what the first columns could represent.

Comment: Ready for **hint #2**...

Comment: Hint number 2 is up!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think (because there is no knowledge tag) it would be:

> Modulo:
>  1 % 5 = 1
>  2 % 7 = 2
>  3 % 2 = 1
>  4 % 3 = 1
>  5 % 5 = 0
>  6 % 3 = 0
>  7 % 6 = 1
>  8 % 3 = 2
>  9 % 7 = 2
>  10 % 4 = 2
>  11 % 7 = **4**
>  12 % **7** = 5